# Would humans with kosher-signs be kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology

If I genetically engineer a human to have split feet and to have a second stomach so they can chew their cud, can I eat them?

Comment: Rav chaim Kaniefsky speaks about a person made from sefer yetzirah

Comment: Well you would still be left wondering if they were a chaya or beheima which would be confusing for kisui hadam and cheilev. So how about you genetically engineer them to have fins and scales? That would avoid these issues. And you wouldn't need shechita, that would help allot too. You know stunning before shchita is not accepted practice.

Comment: Being a fish also has its downsides ,since some hold the fish had to be pulled out if the water

Comment: @sam true but I never understood that asifa idea. Is that liafukei opening ones mouth in the water like a, well, fish, and sucking in some other fish?

Comment: As a side note, I seem to recall hearing that one possible reason consumption of pig was forbidden to Jews was that it's flesh tastes similar to humans. The implications are endless.

Comment: @JJLL I'm so thankful at this point in time that i can't think of anyone to present that idea to to see if it's true.

Comment: I'll try to get a source @user6591. But not tonight. I gotta get to sleep.

Comment: A quick Goohle search turned up several secular non-Jewish sources but I'll keep looking for the Jewish source.

Answer (score 2):

Human beings are not kosher, nor are the un-kosher. Since a person is not a behemah, chayah, or Oph (with the possible exception of Harvey Birdman), no form of shechitah is done on a person to render them fit for consumption. [Eating a person](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14788/is-autocannibalism-halachically-prohibited/14790?s=13%7C0.0616#14790) would be a violation of several different aveiros, such as kavod hames and the obligation to bury, but eating treif would not be among them.