# Is it forbidden to bite off and swallow one's chapped skin?

Tags: eating, meat

Chapped lips can result in parts of skin that are uncomfortable but that can be peeled off. If a person with chapped lips has a habit of using their teeth to pull off the dead skin, are they committing a forbidden act since the skin goes into their mouth? If such is permissible, however, can they then swallow the skin?

**Update**

For clarification, the question on autocannibalism explains that consumption is permissible if that which is consumed stays within your body. What I'm wondering specifically is the following: In the case of dead skin from flaky lips, does swallowing skin removed by teeth qualify as 1) the skin remaining on/in the body and permissible or 2) the skin becoming off/outside the body, thus forbidden?

**Related**

[Is autocannibalism halachically prohibited?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14788/is-autocannibalism-halachically-prohibited?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Swallowing fingernails](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59888/swallowing-fingernails)

Comment: @Deuteronomy Maybe you're right. If I could ask you two quick questions, therefore: 1) In this case and the others, is such permissible? 2) If they're all the same, making my question a duplicate, then should I delete this question?

Comment: So here's a difference: The accepted answer on autocanibalism is that consuming one's own blood would be acceptable if it's in your gums but not if it's removed from the body and then put back in. In this case of my question above, would the removed skin qualify as 1) remaining on/in the body and permissible or 2) becoming off/outside the body, thus forbidden?

Comment: @Deuteronomy Okay, so you're saying it's the latter, i.e., "2) becoming off/outside the body, thus forbidden?" If you're saying it's forbidden, then that isn't what I expected based on reading the linked questions. Unless you meant "former," not latter, and see the lips and mouth as one and the same.

Comment: The autocannibalism question is insufficient, in my mind, to know the specific case about which I'm asking. I've edited my question to better explain.

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2011/02/23/swallowing-skin-from-peeling-lips/