# Is Soylent kosher certified?

Tags: food, product-recommendation, hechsher-certification

The [Soylent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_%28drink%29) company [claims](http://discourse.soylent.me/t/why-was-the-oil-blend-denied-kosher-certification/11946/7) its vegan product (the powder – not the oil blend) is kosher certified, and the powder's [manufacturer](http://www.rfiingredients.com/) does [mention](http://www.rfiingredients.com/certifications.asp) Star-K, but does the powder actually have a hechsher – Star-K or other?

Comment: Wow! -  there actually is a Soylent company!  That was one great movie, with the last performance from the great Emanuel Goldenberg er, Edward G. Robinson...I thought it was amazing that he played a dying man when he knew he was dying...

Comment: @Gary :) But this isn't made from humans. I don't know if Star-K would rely on the [Raavad, Tosafos, Rosh, Ramban, and Rashbah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31227/3073) to certify it, had it indeed been human flesh.

Comment: yeah, it's a good thing they're not selling it in colored varieties!  After reading the site and the VICE article, I can't see anyone eating this stuff as the heart of a nutritious lifestyle.... Imagine, no more breaking bread, just passing out packs n pitchers..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2021, all products in Soylent's "Ready To Drink" product line are certified kosher by the OU: [source on the OU website](https://oukosher.org/product-search/#s=soylent). (This does not include their "Complete Energy" energy drinks.) However, Soylent Powder is not certified, and has not been since 2015.

Answer (score 6):

I asked the Star K about it. Only the powder is certified, not the oil blend that comes with it. This is why they can't put a Star K symbol on the box.

Answer (score 5):

**Feb 2015 Update**

Not anymore.

From [Star-K on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/StarKKosherCertification/posts/350321388492942:0):

> ALERT
>
> Soylent 1.4
>
> Due to product reformulation, Soylent 1.4, a dietary supplement,
>   manufactured by Rosa Labs, Los Angeles, CA, is no longer certified by
>   Star-K. Previous versions of the Soylent product remain certified.

Answer (score 3):

Kosher Certification can be verified in two ways. One, you can ask to see the [Letter of Certification](http://www.star-k.org/directory/comp_list-k.asp), the other is to [contact the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/comments_questions.asp) and ask them.

It isn't listed on the Star-K's website, and from the way your links present the representation of Kosher it may be that the company is buying Kosher product but not itself receiving certification for their own packaging. It could also be that it is listed on the Star-K's website under a corporate name that is different than the brand name, or that the website information is not up to date.

The issue with the company saying they are packaging Star-K certified product without themselves having the certification is that you only have the company's representation that this is what they are doing, and that should not be construed as Star-K certification in the generally understood sense. CYLOR.

Comment: [Apparently](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0421/5993/files/SoylentNutritionFacts.jpg) the corporate name is [Rosa Labs](http://www.rosalabs.com/), but that isn't listed either.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the powder is certified by the Star-K*:

> FW: Question about Rosa Labs
>   Fri, Jun 27, 2014 at 10:43 AM
>
> Yes, the powder is certified by us.
>
> *Rivka Leah Goldman*
>   Database Support Specialist
>   122 Slade
>   Avenue
>  Baltimore, MD  21209
>   
>  410-484-4110 x.220
>   
>  443 334 0137
>   rivkaleah@star-k.org

---

<sup>* Even if the Star-K symbol is not on the label. (Source: Followup question.)</sup>

Comment: Followup question: Is the certification valid if the Star-K is not on the label?

Comment: @Yishai Why wouldn't it be? http://www.aish.com/atr/Is_Coca_Cola_Kosher.html

Comment: It always depends on the conditions the certification applies. Often it is required, e.g. [this](http://www.star-k.org/loc/LetterOfCertification_XF2EVWQ7.pdf) vs. [this](http://www.star-k.org/loc/LetterOfCertification_PCDBTHF3.pdf).

Comment: @Yishai There you go. If it wasn't for you, I wouldn't have asked any of the two questions. :-)